# Error Accessing Object Variables

Tags: java

The following code gives an error:

```
public class Test {
    public Test(int Age){
        int age = Age ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test gg = new Test(5);
        System.out.println(gg.age);
    }

}
```

The error is

> age cannot be resolved or is not a field

How am I able to access `Test.age`?

Comment: that is because `age` is a local variable to `Test` constructor, make it a field

Comment: You should check basics of Java , you can check topic about variables , scopes

Answer (score 3):

You didn't make `age` a field. Just a local variable to the constructor. I think you wanted something like,

```
public class Test {
    int age; // <-- a field. Default access for this example. private or protected
             //     would be more typical, but package level will work here.
    public Test(int Age){
        this.age = Age; // <-- "this." is optional, but indicates a field.
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test gg = new Test(5);
        System.out.println(gg.age);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no field `age` in `Test`. There is a parameter named `age` in `Test`'s constructor, but there is no field. You could declare age with a line like:

```
private int age;
```

inserted above the constructor's first line, and that would be the normal place for an instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

> You are missing the class field, age is local to method and is not accessible to any other method to the same class or outside of the class. It only exist to Test constructor.

```
public class Test {
    public int age;
    public Test(int Age){
         age = Age ;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Test gg = new Test(5);
        System.out.println(gg.age);
    }
}
```